# Why does []mutable{} not compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, mutable

This compiles:

```
[]{};
```

This as well:

```
[]() mutable {};
```

But with this code, compilers throw error messages at me:

```
[] mutable {};
   ^~~~~~~
error: lambda requires '()' before 'mutable'
```

Is there any particular reason why?

Comment: @BaummitAugen reading and understanding standard is a skill by it's own (especially if English not your first language), so it is ok to ask such questions IMHO.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I was wondering, if there is any particular reason, the standard specifies it that way. If not, then yes, I would like this to be changed, because I stumbled over this several times now.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky I can't think of a good reason, most likely an oversight. Write a proposal to change it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a consequence of the way the grammar is written in the standard. I don't know if this is an oversight or not.

A lambda expression starts with a lambda introducer (the brackets), followed by an optional lambda declarator.

The lambda declarator contains the argument list, mutable, attributes, exception specifier and return type. All these are optional, except for the argument list. So if a lambda declarator is present at all, the parentheses must be there.

This is why you can't only have the mutable keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in section 5.1.2  [expr.prim.lambda] in [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (which is the C++14 final draft), that's just the way it falls out of the grammar.  `mutable` is only allowed in a *lambda-declarator* - which includes the brackets.  The whole lambda-declarator is optional though (which is why you can omit the brackets).